# Pin image while it is in background

Tags: javascript, php, pinterest

I'm using API of pinterest in order to pin all images from my website, and it works fine, by the way I'm using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async defer data-pin-color="red"
        data-pin-height="28" data-pin-hover="true"
        src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Now, all tags "img" are pinning right, but I need to do the same while they are in background, example:

```
<div style="background-image:url(blablabla);">
```

Some thoughts would be fine!
Sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want that image should be in code but not load image while screen is not visible right?

If yes then you can use this LazyLoad jQuery library is here: http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-lazyload-any

Comment: Basically, i just need to have the pin option in the div's width background-image..

Comment: Then you can check this PIN example for pintrest http://bradsknutson.com/blog/add-pin-it-button-when-mousing-over-an-image/